# Could not find implicit value inside companion object in Scala Worksheet

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, typeclass, implicit

I am trying to create a type class inside IntelliJ Scala Worksheet. So I started with trait like this

```
trait Show[A] {
  def show(a : A) : String
}
```

and created a companion object

```
object Show {

  def show[A](a: A)(implicit sh: Show[A]) = sh.show(a)

  implicit val intCanShow: Show[Int] =
    new Show[Int] {
      def show(int: Int): String = s"int $int"
    }

}
```

When I try

```
println(Show.show(20))
```

I get this error.

```
Error:(50, 26) could not find implicit value for parameter sh: Show[Int]
println(Show.show(20))
```

But when I take the intCanShow out of the object Show, it works fine. Why cannot scala acess the the implicit inside the object?

Comment: Are you running this in the REPL or in a worksheet? `object Show` is not the companion object for the trait unless they are compiled together as part of the same compilation object. You can use the REPL's `:paste` mode to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes it is in a worksheet. Got it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example appears to work as expected when run as a scala script.
With the following in a file named `test.sh` and marked executable

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala
trait Show[A] {
  def show(a : A) : String
}
object Show {
  def show[A](a: A)(implicit sh: Show[A]) = sh.show(a)

  implicit val intCanShow: Show[Int] =
    new Show[Int] {
      def show(int: Int): String = s"int $int"
    }
}

println(Show.show(20))
```

I observe

```
bash-3.2$ ./test.sh
int 20
```

Comment: yes thanks,I just figured that the worksheet cannot take companion objects. Hence the implicit could not be accessed from the trait.

Answer (score 3):

Implicit resolution tries companion objects so your code seems ok. However for an object to become a *companion* it must satisfy the following two [requirements](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/09/companion-object.html)

1. A companion object is an object with the same name as a class or trait, and
2. is defined in the **same source file** as the associated class or trait.

The following warning means the second requirement is not satisfied:

```
defined object Show
warning: previously defined trait Show is not a companion to object Show.
Companions must be defined together; you may wish to use :paste mode for this.
```

To satisfy second requirement we have to use `Plain` evaluation model in Scala Worksheet, or `:paste` mode in Scala REPL.

### Scala Worksheet Plain evaluation model

To define a companion object in IntelliJ Scala Worksheet change `Run type` to `Plain` like so

1. [`Show Worksheet Settings`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-scala-worksheet-and-ammonite.html#worksheet_actions)
2. Select tab `Settings for *.sc`
3. Change `Run type` from `REPL` to `Plain`

### Scala REPL paste mode

As per @jwvh suggestion, make sure to enter [paste mode](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html#companion-objects)

> If a class or object has a companion, both must be defined in the same
>   file. To define companions in the REPL, either define them on the same
>   line or enter :paste mode.

as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29554506/5205022).