# Intellij Scala worksheet Run type difference explain

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-scala

In Intellij Scala Worksheet support,  what is the difference between the Run types i.e  PLAIN vs REPL ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Plain` evaluation model compiles the whole worksheet in one go before evaluating expressions, whilst `REPL` evaluation model evaluates each expression on the go before moving to the next one.

Adding an expression in `REPL` mode evaluates incrementally just that new expression, whilst in `Plain` mode it would re-interpret the whole worksheet from the beginning.

An example where the difference matters is when defining companion objects. Similarly to how in Scala REPL proper we have to use [`:paste`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913651/5205022) command to define companion, in IntelliJ Scala Worksheet we have to use `Plain` run type.

Answer (score 2):

`REPL` mode as it says `READ EVALUATE PRINT LOOP` is kind of interpreter i.e. each expression will be evaluated after to move to next line.. It is generally used to make `quick logic checks`.

while in `worksheet` mode you need to make an object or class.. worksheet is the traditional OOPS way like we do in java and `whole file is compiled in one go`.